# Java impossible to import class GridCoverage from Geotools

Tags: java, gradle, geotools

I'm trying to import some class from Geotools but its seems objects are not recognize:

```
public Coverage() {
        File file = new File("test.tiff");

        AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(file);
        GridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(file);

        GridCoverage2D coverage = reader.read(null);

    }
```

I already import this lib :

```
geotools_version = '25'
implementation "org.geotools:gt-coverage:${geotools_version}"
```

Source : https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/grid.html

Comment: Find the geotools in mvnrepository.com, use the gradle specification in `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Sambit I already search but when I try to import this my objetcs are not reconize too https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-coverage/24.2

Comment: I don't see a version 25 on mvnrepository - the latest at this time seems to be 24.2. Also, just in case you didn't configure it, you will need to add the OSGeo repository as also stated by the page from mvnrepository.

Comment: @BjørnVester Yes I saw last version was 24.2 but how can I configure OSGeo repository ?

Comment: You need to do the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214940/1703730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `build.gradle`, use the following.

In case of higher version of gradle like 6, use below.

`implementation 'org.geotools:gt-coverage:24.2'`

In case of lower version of gradle like 4, use the below.

`compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-coverage', version: '24.2'`

After making changes, use your favorite ide, refresh the gradle project. Once it is done, you will be able to import the class.

Comment: thank for your answer. When I try to build my project I have this error : > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.geotools.gt-opengis:24.2:.

Comment: Just to clear up some minor things - you can use both the short form 'group:artifact:version' and the map form "group:... name:... version:..." in all versions of Gradle. And as for `compile` vs `implementation`, the latter has been available since version 3.4. Only if you are on a more ancient version than that do you need to use `compile`.

Comment: @BjørnVester, thanks for highlighting the gradle `compile` and `implementation`. Thanks a lot.